# SVG background-image in ::after not showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I have this SCSS code:

```
.page-collapse {

  // ...

  &__title {
    // ...
    position: relative;

    &::after {
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Ctitle%3Eicon-plus%3C/title%3E%3Cg id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square"%3E%3Cg id="modules/cards/events-ext" transform="translate(-183 -1212)" stroke="%232F2F2F" stroke-width="1.5"%3E%3Cg id="ui/plus-black2" transform="translate(184 1213)"%3E%3Cpath d="M7 .5v13m6.5-6.499H.5" id="Line"/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E');
      background-position: 50%;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      content: '';
      height: 1rem;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Which is working fine in Chrome and FF, as can be seen here:

[image]

But not in IE:

[image]

Could it be, that IE does not like background-images in ::after-Elements? Because there is another case, with this code (overriding Bootstraps (4 alpha.6) custom checkbox class:

```
.custom-control-input {

  &:checked {
    ~.custom-control-indicator {
      background-color: $white;
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='12' height='11' viewBox='0 0 12 11' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg id='Styleguide' stroke='none' stroke-width='1' fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke-linecap='square'%3E%3Cg id='styles-forms' transform='translate(-333 -2181)' stroke-width='1.5' stroke='%232F2F2F'%3E%3Cg id='Group-2' transform='translate(329 2141)'%3E%3Cg id='Group'%3E%3Cpath id='icon-checkmark' d='M5 46.744L7.2 49l7.8-8'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
  }
}
```

And this is working in all the browsers. The only difference I see is the first case being in an ::after pseudo element. Also, in IEs dev tools the corresponding CSS part is crossed out:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I only need to support down to IE10

Comment: can you try giving single colon **&:after** as stated here https://alligator.io/css/before-vs-before/ IE8 doen't support **::**

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But I only have to support down to IE10 anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... For some reason, there seems to be some kind of parsing problem in IE and interchanging the ' with " fixed the problem, so changing this:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%3E%3Ctitle%3Eicon-plus%3C/title%3E%3Cg id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square"%3E%3Cg id="modules/cards/events-ext" transform="translate(-183 -1212)" stroke="%232F2F2F" stroke-width="1.5"%3E%3Cg id="ui/plus-black2" transform="translate(184 1213)"%3E%3Cpath d="M7 .5v13m6.5-6.499H.5" id="Line"/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E');
```

to

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ctitle%3Eicon-plus%3C/title%3E%3Cg id='Symbols' stroke='none' stroke-width='1' fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke-linecap='square'%3E%3Cg id='modules/cards/events-ext' transform='translate(-183 -1212)' stroke='%232F2F2F' stroke-width='1.5'%3E%3Cg id='ui/plus-black2' transform='translate(184 1213)'%3E%3Cpath d='M7 .5v13m6.5-6.499H.5' id='Line'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

did the job... the more you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving single colon **&:after** as stated [here](http://alligator.io/css/before-vs-before) IE8 doen't support **::**

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But I only have to support down to IE10 anyways :)